# Loading a shapefile and image using DotSpatial

Tags: shapefile, c#, georeferencing, image, dotspatial

I am using DotSpatial 1.7 in my win form app. I have an image (original image) downloaded from  [Universal Map Downloder](http://www.allmapsoft.com/umd/) and then loaded this file with a shapefile in QGIS and then georeferencing the image in QGIS using shapefile to produce an image that matches with shapefile (modified image).

Now:
I used code below to load two files in my app (shapefile and original image) and it works well and I can select the shapefile:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    map1.AddLayer(@"C:\originalimage.png");
    map1.AddLayer(@"C:\shapefile.shp");

    MapPolygonLayer polygonLayer = default(MapPolygonLayer);
    polygonLayer = (MapPolygonLayer)map1.Layers[1];

    polygonLayer.Symbolizer = new PolygonSymbolizer(Color.FromArgb(0, Color.White), Color.DeepSkyBlue);

    map1.FunctionMode = FunctionMode.Select;
}
```

But, the code below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //map1.AddLayer(@"C:\originalimage.png");
    map1.AddLayer(@"C:\modifiedimage.tiff");
    map1.AddLayer(@"C:\shapefile.shp");

    MapPolygonLayer polygonLayer = default(MapPolygonLayer);
    polygonLayer = (MapPolygonLayer)map1.Layers[1];

    polygonLayer.Symbolizer = new PolygonSymbolizer(Color.FromArgb(0, Color.White), Color.DeepSkyBlue);

    map1.FunctionMode = FunctionMode.Select;
}
```

I can not select the shapefile (modified image is on the shapefile ).
I also convert the .tiff to .png, but it is on the shapefile.

Any idea/solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is for projection. Shapefile is shown as a very very little layer in the bottom left corner of the image. I have no problem with these files in QGIS.

Also see the DotSpatial Documentation or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122130/raster-data-loading-from-filepath-in-dotspatial.

Add code below:

```
 IRaster r = Raster.Open(@"C:\modifiedimage.tiff");
        DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo dest = default(DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo);
        dest = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(4326); 
        r.Projection = dest;
        IMapRasterLayer myLayer = map1.Layers.Add(r);
```